# Why git pull fetches all the branches just from some branches?

Tags: git

Why running `git pull` from some branches (typically `master`) fetches also all the other branches, but running it from differents branches triggers just a fetch and merge attempt from the upstream? In what is `master` different from the other branches?

Answer (score 0):

Because `master` has an upstream typically on a remote, thus in order to pull the remote must be fetched, and doing so fetches also all other branches on that remote